# C# possible to compare string[] to 4 other string[]?

Tags: c#

I've been looking around for a while now for some answers, but I cant find it anywhere.

I need a solution for this in C#:

```
if (stringer[1] == stringer[2]||stringer[3]||stringer[4]||stringer[5])
{

}
```

this obviously doesn't work in C#, so I need a way to do this.

thank you!

Comment: It's `(a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e)`. `(a == b || c || d || e)` doesn't work _anywhere_ (well, except bool, of course :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (stringer.Skip(1).Any(v => v.Equals(stringer[0])) {
    ...
}
```

This code compares every item in the `stringer` array from the second on to the initial item, returning `true` if the initial item is duplicated anywhere else in the array.

Comment: Added ToList(), assuming the original type was an array and not a list, given how the OP intended to access it.

Comment: @MikeAtlas You do not need `ToList` on arrays, the extension method works for arrays and other `IEnumerable<T>` objects as well. Moreover, `T[]` implements `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare each item individually, or use a LINQ solution as above.

if (stringer[1] == stringer[2] || stringer[1] == stringer[3] || and so forth)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a character that will never appear in the strings, you can use it as a delimiter:

```
 ( "|" + stringer[2] + "|" + stringer[3] + "|" ).IndexOf( "|" + stringer[1] + "|" ) >= 0
```

Ugly, ancient technique.